# CWAC CAMERA-switching Front-Back camera not working

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac, cwac-camera

I have integrated [CWAC-CAMERA][1].I am trying to switch between back and front camera by clicking on the button using the below code but its not working.I can see only the default back camera.Where am I going wrong?

```
     private boolean isBackCam=true;
     f = new CameraFragment();
        builder=new SimpleCameraHost.Builder(new DemoCameraHost(getApplicationContext()));
f.setHost(builder.useFullBleedPreview(true).build());
         handleSwitchCamera=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.handleSwitchCamera);
          handleSwitchCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) 
                {


                    if(isBackCam) 
                        {
                            isBackCam=false;
                            builder.useFrontFacingCamera(true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isBackCam=true;
                            builder.useFrontFacingCamera(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Updated according to  CommonsWare answer-

```
 f = new CameraFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.preview_view, f, TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT)
                .commit();
        f2 = new CameraFragment();     
builder=new SimpleCameraHost.Builder(new DemoCameraHost(getApplicationContext()));
        builder2=new SimpleCameraHost.Builder(new DemoCameraHost(getApplicationContext()));
        builder.useFrontFacingCamera(false);
        builder2.useFrontFacingCamera(true);
        f.setHost(builder.useFullBleedPreview(true).build());
        f2.setHost(builder2.useFullBleedPreview(true).build());
handleSwitchCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(isBackCam) {
                Log.e("bhuvnesh","backcam");
                isBackCam=false;


                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.preview_view, f2, TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT)
                        .commit();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("bhuvnesh","frontcam");
                isBackCam=true;


                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.preview_view, f, TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT)
                        .commit();
            }
        }
    });
  [1]: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera
```

Comment: You need to do something with the `Builder` after you configure it, and there is no code in the above listing that does anything with the `Builder` other than call `useFrontFacingCamera()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare checkk now the code in question..i have added few lines which i was using..what exactly you want me to do wid the builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `setHost()` *after* fully configuring the `Builder`. You cannot just change the `Builder` later on and expect a change.

Note that `setHost()` is designed to be called once per fragment. If you want to switch between cameras, you need to switch fragments (one per camera), as the demo app does.

Comment: see in updated question above which i updated after your comment..i am using `f.setHost(builder.useFullBleedPreview(true).build());`

Comment: @Bhuvi: Yes, but you have not called `useFrontFacingCamera()` yet. You are calling `useFrontFacingCamera()` sometime after `setHost()`, when the view is clicked. You have to call `useFrontFacingCamera()` **before** `setHost()`.

Comment: u mean after  `builder.useFrontFacingCamera(true);` i should call `f.setHost(builder.useFullBleedPreview(true).build());`

Comment: @Bhuvi: No, because you cannot change hosts. As I wrote in my answer, if you want to switch between cameras, you need to switch fragments (one per camera), as the demo app does.

Comment: i am doing this in activity

Comment: @Bhuvi: I do not know what "this" is. But you have `f = new CameraFragment();`. `CameraFragment` is a fragment. If you want to switch between cameras, you need to switch fragments (one per camera), as the demo app does.

Comment: @Bhuvi: The demo app is available in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera, in a directory named `demo/`.

Comment: please check the above question code updated according to ur answer..i am still seeing the back camera only..thanks..

Comment: @Bhuvi: As I have written several times, **you have to call `useFrontFacingCamera()` before `setHost()`**. As part of setting up `f` and `f2` originally, call `useFrontFacingCamera()` on each fragment's `Builder`. Then, on the button click, just do the `replace()` transaction.

Comment: i updated according to ur comment..i still seeing back camera only..please check updated code in question..thanks..

Comment: in that demo code i don't see any where coding for switching front-back camera..please provide me link..thanks..

Comment: @Bhuvi: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/demo/MainActivity.java#L102-L130

Comment: okay ..i checked that activity.in that u r creating three instance of DemoCameraFragment std,ffc,current and assigning the fragments std or ffc to current depening upon requirement.But i don't see u have set host or created a builder..i willl be grateful to u  if u can check in question and let me know where am I going wrong..

Comment: @Bhuvi: `setHost()` is called [in `onCreate()` of `DemoCameraFragment`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/demo/DemoCameraFragment.java#L76). Feel free to learn how to use tools like **`grep`**, or the "find" function in your IDE, or the search field in GitHub, to search code for certain strings like "setHost" in a set of source files.